# npm lock-file changes without installing any package

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install, package-lock.json

Currently, I have a small issue with `package-lock` file between difference OS system(Mac OS / Linux)

My colleague and me use `makefile` to run project and the contained commend is only `npm install` and `npm run start`, however when we run a project, the `package-lock` file has been changed. please refers the image below.

Example

[image]

I read the official document but couldn't find related answer.
I slightly suspect this might come from the OS difference, but not sure about it.

Does anyone know why this un-wanted changing occurs?

Thank you!

Version:

```
         me    |   colleagu
node. v16.14.2 | v17.6.0
npm. v8.5.5    | v8.5.1
```

Comment: `npm install` can/does update `package-lock.json`, because `package.json` may have been updated with dependencies being updated: removed, added, or changed. The differences you are seeing (the elision of the `requires` property is likely due to the differences in `npm` versions between you and your partner. You might want to consider using [`npm ci`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/commands/npm-ci) to do you installs, assuming package.json has not been updated. `npm ci` is the "continuous integration" install and will never update `package-lock.json`.

Comment: Thank you for the reply and sorry for late comment @NicholasCarey ,

I already tried `npm ci` but, we still have some issues.
What if we want to install or update a specific package, anyway `npm install` command would be needed, then the un-wanted structure change in `package-lock` might be again. does it any other way to try?